# How to read colon seperated values from txt file in java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to read in the data from a text file that is formatted like this:

```
Operation: ADDITION Attempts: 3
```

The data I'm trying to read in is the operation and the number of attempts for each line so for example ADDITION and the number 3

This is as far as I could get and I'm still not certain.

```
File inputFile = new File("mathFile.txt");
 Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);

 while(input.hasNext())
    {
        String token = input.nextLine();
        String[] details = token.split("Operation:");
        String operation = details[0];
}
```

Comment: You're on the right track, but before you post please take the time to do some [research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/). If what you find doesn't help you, post what you found and the reason it was not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Model: line representation
public final class MathFileLine {

    private final String operation;
    private final int attempts;

    public MathFileLine(String operation, int attempts) {
        this.operation = operation;
        this.attempts = attempts;
    }

}

// client code
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    List<MathFileLine> lines = readMathFile(Paths.get("mathFile.txt"));
}
```

#### #1: Use Stream to read lines with RegEx

```
public static List<MathFileLine> readMathFile(Path path) throws IOException {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^Operation:\\s+(?<operation>\\w+)\\s+Attempts:\\s+(?<attempts>\\d+)$");
    return Files.lines(path)
                .map(pattern::matcher)
                .filter(Matcher::matches)
                .map(matcher -> new MathFileLine(matcher.group("operation"), Integer.parseInt(matcher.group("attempts"))))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

#### #2: Use Scanner with custom delimiter to read pairs

```
public static List<MathFileLine> readMathFile(Path path) throws IOException {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(path.toFile())) {
        scan.useDelimiter("\\s*(?:Operation:|Attempts:)?\\s+");
        List<MathFileLine> lines = new LinkedList<>();

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            lines.add(new MathFileLine(scan.next(), scan.nextInt()));
        }

        return lines;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to split on spaces:

```
String[] parts = token.split(" ");
String operation = parts[1];
String attempts = parts[3];
```

If you want to get fancier, you can use Regex:

```
String token = "Operation: ADDITION Attempts: 3";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^Operation: (\\w+) Attempts: (\\d+)$").matcher(token);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String operation = matcher.group(1);
    String attempts = matcher.group(2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways you can read a text file and split the lines based on some delimiter. In addition to all the other answers here, following is yet another answer that is succinct and self-explanatory.

(1) **Read the lines of a file**

```
List<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("mathFile.txt")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(2) **Parse what you want from each line**

```
List<String> operations = lines.stream().map(line -> line.split("Operation:")[0]).collect(Collectors.toList());
```